# SCSS linter for Codemirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror, lint, scss-lint, linter

How can I make linter work in Codemirror for SCSS mode?

If I use `css-lint.js` then I receive errors such as, `Unknown @ rule: &mixin`.

Comment: At this point you can't. The CodeMirror CSS linter is CSSLint (http://csslint.net/js/csslint.js) and it doesn't support SCSS. I haven't been able to find any SCSS linters that work with CodeMirror

Comment: I am hoping there will be an `scssslint.js` that I can download and use or somebody can give me some help modifying `csslint.js`. SCSS is essential for the CMS I am making, however, it's likely most of my clients won't of even heard of SCSS. Therefore, lint mode is necessary.

Comment: @DanBray  Is my answer OK for you?

Comment: Yes, your answer is excellent. There is however a bug. I receive an error "Mixed tabs and spaces (indentation)"  just for using tabs, despite not mixing tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The result below is mainly based on [**sass-lint**](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint)

## Live demo:

http://blackmiaool.com/soa/43127937/cm.html

## Source Code

https://github.com/blackmiaool/sass-lint

and

https://github.com/blackmiaool/soa/tree/gh-pages/43127937

## How?

It's really a big project, allow me to introduce it step by step.

#### What do we have?

You want a scss-linter, but there is just a [css-linter](http://codemirror.net/demo/lint.html) in codemirror now. And there is a [**sass-lint**](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint) which has 1k star on github. The [**sass-lint**](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint)  just support nodejs environment (it depends on `fs`, `path` and something alike) and **can be used to lint scss**.

#### What should we do?

According to [css-lint](http://codemirror.net/demo/lint.html), we should have a *scss-lint.js* which registers the scss linter and a *scsslint.js* which is used to lint scss. Now let's do it.

#### scss-lint.js

Just refer to [css-lint.js](http://codemirror.net/addon/lint/css-lint.js), our scss-lint.js is this:

```js
// CodeMirror, copyright (c) by Marijn Haverbeke and others
// Distributed under an MIT license: http://codemirror.net/LICENSE


(function (mod) {
    if (typeof exports == "object" && typeof module == "object") // CommonJS
        mod(require("../../lib/codemirror"));
    else if (typeof define == "function" && define.amd) // AMD
        define(["../../lib/codemirror"], mod);
    else // Plain browser env
        mod(CodeMirror);
})(function (CodeMirror) {
    "use strict";

    CodeMirror.registerHelper("lint", "scss", function (text, options) {        
        var found = [];
        if (!window.SCSSLint) return found;
        var results = SCSSLint.verify(text, options),
            messages = results.messages,
            message = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            message = messages[i];
            var startLine = message.line - 1,
                endLine = message.line - 1,
                startCol = message.col - 1,
                endCol = message.col;
            found.push({
                from: CodeMirror.Pos(startLine, startCol),
                to: CodeMirror.Pos(endLine, endCol),
                message: message.message,
                severity: message.type
            });
        }
        return found;
    });

});
```

It depends on `window.SCSSLint`.

#### from scss-lint to scsslint.js

1. We don't actually have files, so we just use its [`lintText`](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/blob/d81cc0ef4055c55ee0da17052cd3f0a0e7a1694f/index.js#L103) function.
2. We run it in browser, so better to avoid [yaml](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/tree/d81cc0ef4055c55ee0da17052cd3f0a0e7a1694f/data). Change yaml files to json.
3. We don't have `fs` and `path` in browser, so just replace them with requiring json.
4. We need a tool to integrate all the file in the project into a single file, so we use webpack here.
5. Many other details.

#### Finally

Use it in browser:

html:

```
<script src="./dist/scsslint.js"></script>
<script src="./cm/scss-lint.js"></script>
```

js:

```
CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code-css"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: "text/x-scss",
    gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
    lint: {
        options: {
            rules: {//try to remove this rule
                "no-empty-rulesets": 1,
            }
        }
    }
});
```

#### How to build your own `scsslint`?

1. Download my answer [repo](https://github.com/blackmiaool/soa)
2. Enter the 43127937 directory
3. Clone my [sass-lint](https://github.com/blackmiaool/sass-lint) there
4. Enter the sass-lint directory
5. `npm i && cd .. && npm i && webpack`
6. check the `dist` directory

#### And

My [sass-lint](https://github.com/blackmiaool/sass-lint) fork is supposed to be published to npm, but it's mostly not my work. I will ask the maintainers of the orignal repo what they think about it.

## TL;DR

Insert this snippet to your html:

```
<script src="http://blackmiaool.com/soa/43127937/dist/scsslint.js"></script>
<script src="http://blackmiaool.com/soa/43127937/cm/scss-lint.js"></script>
```

Config your codemirror like this:

```js
CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code-css"), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  mode: "text/x-scss",
  gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
  lint: {
    options: {
      rules: {
        "no-empty-rulesets": 1,
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have it working. The only problem I have, is I receive "Mixed tabs and spaces (indentation)" error every time I use tabs (I always use tabs), despite not mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: I fixed that problem by adding `"indentation": 0` to the rules below `"no-empty-rulesets": 1`

Comment: @DanBray  According to the [documentation](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/blob/develop/docs/rules/indentation.md), it may be caused by the spaces used elsewhere in the file

Comment: There's still a bug. I've just tested it with absolutely no spaces in the entire file, and I still receive the error.

Comment: @DanBray  try this: "indentation":[ 2, { "size": "tab" } ]

Comment: How to add or remove rules? I just added those two lines beneath TL;DR,

Comment: I want to remove "!important" rule

Comment: @AliRasheed you can declare ur own url under the "rules" option. For example: `"no-empty-rulesets": 0` to disable `no-empty-rulesets` rule

Comment: Can you list me those errors that would crash SASS compiler?

Comment: @AliRasheed I can't, I don't even know the syntax of sass. Try to ask a new question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @blackmiaool I added "no-important: false"; but it doesn't allow !important to be written.

Comment: @AliRasheed Try "no-important":0